# Nested Transactions In EF6

Tags: entity-framework

I have a method where the DBContext is pass in (this is only POC code).

I then try to open another nested transaction, With this code

```
using (var cxt = new TestEntities(context.Database.Connection, false))
{           
  using (DbContextTransaction dbContextTransaction = cxt.Database.BeginTransaction())
  {
```

The call to "BeginTransaction" gives this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException' occurred in TestEF6.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715
```

I have a Database First Model
Any clues?

Regards 
GregJF

Comment: Could you also post the connection string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework UnintentionalCodeFirstException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406991/entity-framework-unintentionalcodefirstexception)