# EF Designer from database - no table in generated code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My designer from database has generated files from database from one table. I was expecting that it will open visual designer window, but it was empty. I looked into context code and found that my table is missing:

```
namespace DatabaseFirstDemo
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class DatabaseFirstDemoEntities1 : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseFirstDemoEntities1()
            : base("name=DatabaseFirstDemoEntities1")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

    }
}
```

I was expecting DbSet line:

```
public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts {get;set;}
```

Where is my table and how to fix this?

UPD: I did update model from database, but this not helped:

[image]

My connection string is as follows:

```
<add name="DatabaseFirstDemoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BlogModel.csdl|res://*/BlogModel.ssdl|res://*/BlogModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DatabaseFirstDemo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework UnintentionalCodeFirstException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406991/entity-framework-unintentionalcodefirstexception)

Comment: Double click on the `.edmx` file in your project, are any tables shown? If not, right click in an empty space and choose `Update Model from Database`, are any tables shown?

Comment: The table is showing under the `Add` tab suggesting you haven't added it to your model. In the screenshot you showed did you click `Finish` or `Cancel`? I'm assuming the issue might be to do with permissions as per you last post, what permissions did you give? I think you need `[db_datareader]`, `[db_datawriter]` and `[db_ddladmin]`

Comment: I have updated question body with connection string. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: Where I must set permitions for DB?

Comment: Connection string looks fine to me. The permissions are set on the database itself, for example in MS SQL you'd typically do it in Management Studio. You haven't mentioned what you're using...

Comment: I have added required permition for dbo in Management Studio, but this not helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156653/discussion-between-vico-and-equalsk).